# How to query multiple columns using PanacheMongoRepository in Java

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a use case to query multiple columns on a MongoDB collection, which should result in a single document,
I'm using the find method as follows -

```
find("countryCode = ?1 and languageId = ?2", "USA", "EN")
```

In the DB, there is a document with `"countryCode": "USA", "languageId": "EN"`,
But the find method result is coming as null.

What could be the issue?

Ref -
https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#query-parameters

Comment: did you call `.list() `or `.firstResult()` after the `.find(...)` method ?

Comment: yes I called .firstResult() after doing find